# Azure DB connection unsuccesfull in wsl2

Tags: mysql, azure, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

```
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
 host: "host.mysql.database.azure.com",
 user: "user",
 password: "password",
 database: "db",
 port: 3306,
 waitForConnections: true,
 connectionLimit: 10,
 queueLimit: 0,
});

async function init() {
 // Initialize the connection
 try {
 const connection = await pool.getConnection();
 console.log("Connected to the MySQL server.");
 connection.release();
  } catch (error) {
 console.error(`Error connecting to the MySQL server : ${error.message}`);
  }
}

init();
```

when i run this code in win11 "Connected to the MySQL server". but in wsl2 (ubuntu) "Error connecting to the MySQL server" why this is happening? and how can i fix this

mysql server hosted on Azure cant be accesed in wsl2(ubuntu) but can be accesed in win11

but when i tried to connect with "mysql --host=host.mysql.database.azure.com --user=user --password=password" in wsl2 its working

Answer (score 0):

> Error connecting to the MySQL server

This error causes because of not providing the `.pem` file path in the code. The same error was resolved by providing that file path, you can download that file `networking` under `settings` in Azure `mysqlserver` as shown below.
[image]

Move the file into the project file path and provide that path in the code. Below is the sample code which connected successfully to the Azure MySQL and retrieved data from the MySQL Database.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

async function main() {
    try {
        // Create a MySQL connection using the provided connection string
        const conn = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: "*******",
            user: "user91",
            password: "*****",
            database: "db",
            port: 3306,
            ssl: {
                ca: fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/*****.crt.pem")
            }
        });

        console.log("Connected to the MySQL server.");

        const [rows, fields] = await conn.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1');

        console.log(rows); 

        conn.end();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error connecting to the MySQL server: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

main();
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank Balaji. But i my case I had install mysql2 with sudo npm .